# Connecting Thunderbolt Display to Non-Thunderbolt MacBook (mid 2010)

Tags: macbook, hdmi, thunderbolt

I have an old MacBook Pro (Mid 2010 / Pre Thunderbolt) and an extra ThunderBolt 27" which I wanted to connect to the laptop.

According to Apple and a ton of posts online (dated around 2011) this is not possible since Thunderbolt is only supported on Thunderbolt enabled devices starting from Mid 2011 ranges.

A quick search reviled that there are [Thunderbolt to HDMI](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Mini-DP-Thunderbolt-to-DVI-VGA-HDMI-Adapter-3-in1-for-Apple-MacBook-Pro-Air-iMAC/1785236563.html?s=p) and [MiniDisplay to HDMI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C28L51G) adapters. So I figure Thunderbolt to HDMI + Male to Male HDMI + HDMI to Mini Display => Old MacBook with shiny Thunderbolt.

Is this going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at it the wrong way round. It doesn't start Thunderbolt to HDMI... it *ends* HDMI to Thunderbolt - though you'd be better off going straight from Mini DP >Thunderbolt...

...except that http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219 would lead me to believe it can't be done.

Comment: You are right I got the flow messed up. As you said DP > Thunderbolt  will NOT work and that's official. I went for HDMI in the middle solution because I figured HDMI would be the magic that will make this whole thing work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if there was a workaround, it would be covered in that KB article.

Comment: That's what I feared :D

Comment: I accepted this as the answer after I finally understood what you meant. Also according to these posts (http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=19647355#post19647355 and http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1212564) the answer is definitely...No.